# Visualising classif.rpart tree from mlr package in r

Tags: r

May I know how to visualize the tree model generated in mlr `classif.rpart` or is it possible to print the tree rules

```
 makeatree <- makeLearner("classif.rpart", predict.type = "response")

 set_cv <- makeResampleDesc("CV",iters = 3L)

 gs <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("minsplit",lower = 10, upper = 50),makeIntegerParam("minbucket", lower = 5, upper = 50),makeNumericParam("cp", lower = 0.001, upper = 0.2))

 gscontrol <- makeTuneControlGrid()

 stune <- tuneParams(learner = makeatree, resampling = set_cv, task = trainTask, par.set = gs, control = gscontrol, measures = acc)

t.tree <- setHyperPars(makeatree, par.vals = stune$x)

tpmodel <- predict(t.rpart, testTask)

t.rpart <- train(t.tree, trainTask)
```

here Visualizing the tree model in `rpart.plot()` will not work as this is not rpart object, Thanks in advance